# How to add assets to WSO2 Governance Registry using SOAP UI or Java

Tags: java, web-services, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am new to WSO2 Governance Registry, I am using the version v5.4.0.

After successfully creating custom extension using RXT and exporting the wsdl from /services/extension? wsdl want to add assets to registry using a Java application.

I have created a soapUI project from wsdl but the add operation only takes `<ser:info xmlns:ser="http://services.add.<assettype>.governance.carbon.wso2.org">` type.

How do I create this? What happened to my attributes in RXT?

I am still trying to wrap my mind around WSO2 Governance Registry and would appreciate any pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to add assets using a remote java application, I think better to do it via the Governance Java API or REST API because it is simpler and cleaner.

if you prefer to use Governance Java API, please refer "[Governance API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Governance+API)" and "[Configurable Governance Artifacts with API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance460/Configurable+Governance+Artifacts+with+API)"

If you like to use Governance REST API, you can refer "[Governance REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance540/Governance+REST+API)" doc.

Comment: Thanks Chandana, in both cases you describe, one needs to know all the attribute names which are not refactoring safe, I am looking for something like when you ass extensions as OSGi jar you get the real model in the wsdl e.g. addStudent(Student student), with RXT I am getting addStudent(String student). It seems I need to create the XML representation of Student instead of using POJO

Comment: There is no out of the box POJO object to achieve your requirement. If you know the RXT(Ex: student) attributes, you will be able to create custom POJO which is wrapped with governance artifact layer.